# How to use bibitem entries with BibTeX and apply it with chapterbib/multibib?

Tags: bibliographies, multibib

I wrote a journal article some time ago that, luckily, was accepted. The publisher kindly sent me the `LaTeX` file derived from the article. I now want to include the `LaTeX` code into my PhD thesis. It is fully working except for the bibliography. The publisher included the bibliography in an `\thebibliography` environment and used `\bibitem` for each entry.
The bibliography has the following format:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem{}
{\AA}gren, A., Buffam, I., Berggren, M., Bishop, K., Jansson, M., and Laudon,
H.: Dissolved organic carbon characteristics in boreal streams in a
forest-wetland gradient during the transition between winter and summer, J.
Geophys. Res.-Biogeo., 113, G03031, \href{http://dx.doi.org/10.1029/2007JG000674}{doi:10.1029/2007JG000674}, 2008.

\bibitem{}
Alewell, C., Lischeid, G., Hell, U., and Manderscheid, B.: High temporal
resolution of ion fluxes in semi-natural ecosystems -- gain of information or
waste of resources? Biogeochemistry, 69, 19--35,
\href{http://dx.doi.org/10.1023/B:BIOG.0000031029.46798.7f}{doi:10.1023/B:BIOG.0000031029.46798.7f}, 2004.

\end{thebibliography}
```

My question now is, how can I include this bibliography into my document using chapterbib or multibib. I want a listed bibliography after every section. I tried the website `text2bib` and the perl script `tex2bib` but it resulted in lots of errors (not recognizing the author or year published). Any google-fu was to no avail. I greatly appreciate any direct help or pointing me to the right link/post. I hope I made myself clear. Please let me know if and how I can improve this question.

Comment: I guess the simplest thing to do would be to copy-paste the elements of bibitems into a bib file manager such as JabRef, and save the result as a `.bib` file. Also, note it is easy to make bibliographies per chapter with `biblatex` (see §3.7.4, *Bibliography Sections*, of the documentation).

Comment: I already tried to import the content from the bibliography into JabRef but it didn't do anything. Can you explain me how you would do it using JabRef? I am already using BibLaTeX. I would like to copy the content from the bibliography into a .bib file that then I can add to the resources.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with ‘It didn't do anything’?

Comment: It gives a status report saying "could not find a suitable import format".

Comment: I see. What you should do is chopping each item into small chunks which correspond to a field, possibly modify some details, choose the correct entry, add a bibtex key. JabRef will tell you if there are syntax errors.

Comment: A little `awk`. A little `sed`. That would do it. Otherwise as @Bernard says. Or get the entry information again from an online service in BibTeX format.

Comment: A manual import into a `.bib` file is the best solution. There are at least two reasons: (1) It is unwise to leave what goes in the `title` field in lowercase because it is easier to 'lowercase' (meant as a verb) words in a title than it is to 'titlecase'  them; and (2), it may well be that other journals will want you to abbreviate the journal title differently, so you want to use `@string`s for journal titles if you are going (to need) to abbreviate them.